# Core Data - please help me to build right data model

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

There is a model of flash card for learning terms and definition.
I've created entity Card with the following attributes:

packTitle
def
level
term

Cards in a set with definite theme have the same packTitle, for example animals.
To populate all available packTitles I get an array

```
NSArray *arrayOfTitles = [[[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]
                                           valueForKey:@"packTitle"]
                                       valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

to get all cards with definite packTitle

```
- (NSArray *) cardsForPackTitle:(NSString * )selectedPackTitle {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(packTitle like %@)", selectedPackTitle];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *fetchedCards =  [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error ];

    [fetchRequest release];

     return fetchedCards;  

}
```

All above works, but when I need to delete cards with definite packTitle, it seems that code 
become to long for the simple task.

The question: should I built the data model in may case some other way? I'm new to Core Data, sorry if the question is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should most probably do it differently. It doesn't make much sense to repeatedly store "animal" in various cards just to signify they're animal cards.

What you should (probably) do is create another entity called `Pack`. This entity should have the `title` attribute, and the `cards` one-to-many relationship. Then connect the `cards` relationship to your `Card` entity. (Remove the `packTitle` attribute from the `Card` entity.)

You should also read the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) to learn more about Core Data. It's a bit difficult to understand at first, but after a couple of reads and a little bit of practice it starts to make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer confirmed me that I'm moving in a right direction.